# If an entire forest was pulled together into one "grafted tree" by the use of Demi-god worthy magic, what would that tree be like?

Tags: flora, creature-design

In my world, Yggdralon Trees are absolutely massive trees that were once vast forests. Tales claim that they were created by the Demi-gods. They pulled the forests around them and wrapped the trees together binding them into giant cacoons.

I picture about 10-20 billion trees twisting around one another and compressing together to make a mega-tree big enough for an entire nation to live around its trunk.

The question I suppose is how would grafting work in this case? Granted this is all being done by magic means and I can just write it off as such, but I want some idea of if this is even feasible. Would certain species survive and others die? What would need to occur for it to survive as one entity?

Also, what might it end up looking like? Could every other branch hold a different kind of foliage?

I know of the 40-Fruit tree, and I assume that might shed some light on my idea, but I would like to get others' perspectives on this as well.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding Drask, please take the [tour] and when you have a moment read-up in the [help] about how we work. We deal with single, focused questions here, you have given us several. You can [edit] down to a single question to make it answerable within the requirements laid out in the help center. (From review).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible height and size of a giant tree on an Earth-like planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112056/possible-height-and-size-of-a-giant-tree-on-an-earth-like-planet)

Answer (score 2):

first off welcome to worldbuilding SE.(i know i'm new too) now onto the question ill go down the list. first we have would some species survive and other die? Yes but this all depends. species that run fast are at a disadvantage here because well there wouldn't be as much open space, id assume more nimble species would thrive and ones that climb are very advantaged. I don't think they would die out but some populations would decrease.

Second we have What would need to occur for it to survive as one entity? i assume you are talking about this tree being one living thing and it supporting its ecosystem, correct? i think it would change but overall it would stay similar to its original for, population changed a bit but it would live.

Next we have what might it end up looking like? a giant network of trees filled with animals and plants. you could describe it as

> "*A massive network of life, all connected stretching far, tall, and
>   wide upwards and out. Everything combined as one.*"

-topcode

or something like that but more poetic because i'm not good at poetry.

finally we have Could every other branch hold a different kind of foliage? I say not every branch but there should be variety. anyways hope this is what you were looking for.

(PS: if you do use my poetic quote maybe credit me as some guy in the story or as like a footnote. cool thanks.)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, trees on the scale you are probably picturing simply cannot exist for a few reasons.

The most notable is a principle called the square-cube law.  Basically as you scale any object up, it's mass increases with a power of 3 where as it's material integrity (measured as a cross section) scales up at a power of 2 meaning that really big things always collapse in on themselves; so, a tree design that works at 100ft tall won't necessarily work at 1000 ft tall.

The second reason is a limitation of photosynthesis.  The thicker you make a tree canopy, the less light reaches the bottom so making a tree too tall means that it can not get enough sunlight to sustain it.

The third limiting factor is a principle called Gigantothermy where by organisms with even very limited metabolic thermal output can maintain high internal temperatures just by being big enough.  A super giant tree would become so hot at the core of its trunk that it would cook itself from the inside out.

So to make a super giant tree it would need to have lots of gaps in it, and not be too tall, but as long as you do this, you could make it have whatever radius you want... basically it would have to look like a forest (probably not what you were hoping for...)

But there may be a way to get something that looks sort of like a single giant tree made of many species of trees.  Unlike wood, granite can be very tall without collapsing on itself.  Your trees could be completely intertwined and grafted onto a tall and very steep mountain like the one below.  Then the "branches" would be many many whole trees intertwined and wrapping around it into what people would see as a single giant tree.

[image]